# in React Typewriter-effect font-size is not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, react-hooks

fon-size in CSS is not working in React typewriter-effect, how do i change the font size then ??

React code

```
<div className='chan'>
               <Typewriter
  onInit={(typewriter) => {
    typewriter.typeString("Aman Chauhan").pauseFor(1500).start();
  }}
  options={{
    loop: true
  }}
/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.chan{
    color: var(--red);
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 100px;
}
```

Comment: are you using react-typewriter-effect?
there is a textStyle prop that you can use to style the text

Answer (score 1):

According to the Document, use wrapperClassName to customize the style of the wrapper. Use cursorClassName to customize the style of the cursor.

index.jsx

```
<Typewriter
  onInit={(typewriter) => {
    typewriter.typeString("Aman Chauhan").pauseFor(1500).start();
  }}
  options={{
    loop: true,
    wrapperClassName: styles.typeWriterText,
  }}
/>
```

index.css

```
.typeWriterText {
      font-size: 40px;
}
```